# How can solve the next.js

Tags: next.js

```
PS C:\Users\hp\Desktop\next\next> npm start

> publicpages-next@0.1.0 start
> next start

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\next\next\.next\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop\\next\\next\\.next\\BUILD_ID'
}
```

How to Run Next js vscode local run working on solve that?

Comment: You did not build your nextjs app. Build it first

Answer (score 0):

type `npm run build`

then
`npm run start`